# Reduce silence time between two words in Julius speech recognition

Tags: julius-speech

I have successfully completed a speech recognition application with  [Julius](http://julius.osdn.jp/en_index.php) speech recognition for  English, but the problem is:

I want to reduce the silence time between two words to identify both words.

Is there a way to configure this silence time between two words?

Answer (score 0):

> reduce the silence time between two words

there's no such thing in speech recognition. Speaker can make short pause between words if he/she wants, or speak two words without pause between them. A special skippable short pause model is added to the end of each word hypothesis during decoding to take care of this situation automatically. Please refer to [Tutorial in HTK Book](http://htk.eng.cam.ac.uk/) to understand short pause modeling in speech recognition.